# IE - <base> tag works fine with <a href> but not with JS document.location

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a problem with `<base>` tag in Internet Explorer (I used IE11 for testing). While I managed to make my links works when using `<a href>` tag, it still doesn't work if I try to use JS `document.location`

You can see it live here (scroll down and see two links at the very bottom of the screen): one is using

`<a href="test.html">Go to <strong>test.html</strong></a>`

and the other one

`<a href="javascript:window.document.location='test.html';">Go to <strong>test.html</strong></a>`

https://gb.mynetmoto.com/shop.cfm/motorcycle-tyres.html

First works fine, the second didn't. Why? Any ideas?

**Make sure you use IE** because it works fine in any other browsers...

Comment: `<a href="javascript:window.document.location='test.html';">` – wow, can you do more stuff wrong in one single line? You should use event handlers, not `javascript:` in a `href` attribute. And `window.document.location=` is wrong on multiple levels. Firstly, it is `window.location`, and secondly, you should not overwrite the whole object, but assign a new value to its `href` property. `window.location.href="foo"`, that’s the _correct_ way of using this.

Comment: Great! Too bad you didn't answer to my question. Even using `window.location.href` will not fix the problem. See it yourself, reload that page. Any other browser except IE had no problem with javascript in href, document.location or whatever. Did you try to help or just making conversation?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`document.baseURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/baseURI) instead.

> The base URL of a document defaults to the document's address (as
>   displayed by the browser and available in window.location), but can
>   change from the default:
>
> When an HTML `<base>` tag is found in the document; When this is a new
>   document created dynamically. See the Base URLs section of the HTML
>   Living standard for details.
>
> You can use `document.baseURI` to obtain the base URL of a document.
>   Note that obtaining the base URL for a document may return different
>   URLs over time if the  tags or the document's location change.

Comment: Thanks Bram. You solution kind of works... but not totally. First, I modified by footer to include a link with your solution. It goes there, the URL remains the same in the browser window. That's ok, let's say. The problem is that it doesn't solve some important problems for me. For instance, I use BootstrapDialog and there is a `load('url')` method there. And there still not works cause I can't apply your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed most of the problems using Location assign() Method

```
location.assign("uri");
```

More about this method here:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_assign.asp